# cgi script scrollable check_box

Tags: html, cgi, cgi-bin

I am trying to convert my scrolling_list  I have on my web page which back by cgi script to scrollable check_box. is this possible on cgi? I have read a lot can be done on Java. but I am wondering if it can be done on cgi? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ok, currently my script include

```
                  scrolling_list    (-name   => 'test',

                       -default=> "NONE",

                       -values => ['1','2','3', '4'],

                       -multiple => 'true',

                       -size => 7,

                         ),
```

as you know this is scrolling the list but doesn't have check box to select individually.if I create checkbox_group, I can select individually but the list is not scrollable.

```
             checkbox_group    (-name   => 'test',

                       -default=> "NONE",

                       -values => ['1','2','3', '4'], 

                       -multiple => 'true',

                        -linebreak=>'yes',

                       -size => 7,

                         ),
```

so simply I need the combination of these two. thanks!!